# How to check iOS 10 deprecated methods in Xcode 8?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios10, xcode8

My app uses `UIUserNotificationSettings`, which I noticed is [deprecated in iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiusernotificationsettings). However Xcode isn't displaying a Buildtime deprecation error for this method. How can I make Xcode display these newly deprecated methods?

Comment: Xcode generally don't, Apple expect you to look up the documentation, ie. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiusernotificationsettings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing deprecated warnings because you're likely targeting an OS that's pre-10.0. If you wanted to see the warnings, change your deployment target to 10.0 and the 10.0 deprecation warnings will appear.